# Replace CSS tags from string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to replace

```
<span style="text-decoration: underline;">
```

as

and `</span>` to `</u></span>`

Only replace `</span>` for `<span style="text-decoration: underline;">`

No need to replace `</span>` for `<span style="color: #9bbb59;">`

```
 declare @text varchar(max)
 set @text = 'i want to how tags are
 <span style="color: #9bbb59;">
   <span style="text-decoration: underline;">working</span>
 </span>'
```

Expected Result:

```
I want to how tags are 
<span style="color: #9bbb59;">
 <span style="text-decoration: underline;">
   <u>working</u>
 </span>
</span>
```

Comment: I need to to replace <span style="text-decoration: underline;">  by <span style="text-decoration: underline;"><u> and </span> by </u></span>. no need to replace all </span>. Only need to replace for underline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with XML functions:

```
 DECLARE @text VARCHAR(MAX)
 SET @text = 'i want to how tags are
 <span style="color: #9bbb59;">
   <span style="text-decoration: underline;">working</span>
   <span style="text-decoration: underline;"><i>here</i></span>
   <span style="text-decoration: underline;">now</span>
 </span>';

 -- Convert to XML
 DECLARE @xml xml = CONVERT(XML, @text);

 -- Get the count of nodes to be updated
 DECLARE @nodeCount INT = @xml.value('count(//span[@style="text-decoration: underline;"])', 'int');
 DECLARE @i INT = 1;
 DECLARE @nodeValue XML;
 DECLARE @newValue XML;

 -- Iterate thru on the nodes
 WHILE (@i <= @nodeCount) BEGIN

    -- Get the original node value
    SET @nodeValue = @xml.query('(//span[@style="text-decoration: underline;"][sql:variable("@i")])/*')
    SET @nodeValue = IIF(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @nodeValue) = N'', @xml.query('(//span[@style="text-decoration: underline;"][sql:variable("@i")])/text()'), @nodeValue)

    -- Create the new node value
    SET @newValue = N'<u></u>';
    SET @newValue.modify('
        insert sql:variable("@nodeValue")
        into (//u)[1]
    ');

    -- Remove child nodes
    SET @xml.modify('
        delete (//span[@style="text-decoration: underline;"][sql:variable("@i")]/*)
    ');

    -- Remove textual data
    SET @xml.modify('
        replace value of (//span[@style="text-decoration: underline;"][sql:variable("@i")]/text())[1]
        with ""
    ');

    -- Add the new value as child
    SET @xml.modify('
        insert sql:variable("@newValue")
        into (//span[@style="text-decoration: underline;"])[sql:variable("@i")][1]'
    );  

    SET @i = @i+1;
END;
SELECT @xml, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @xml);
```

Note, that this won't work if the original text can't be converted to XML.

Comment: Thanks for Spending your time and the above query getting error: "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
Incorrect syntax near '='."

Comment: @B.Muthamizhselvi which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @B.Muthamizhselvi Since that is the first occurence of a unicode string literal (`N''`) in this code, I am wondering if we are really talking about Micrsoft SQL Server. Maybe your tag is wrong.

Comment: :Sorry i am using old version 2008R2.Now its working in 2017. Thank you so much for spending your time.IIF function is not introduced in 2008R2

Answer (score 0):

Not sure is it best or not but try below query:

```
DECLARE @MainString NVARCHAR(MAX) ='i want to how tags are <span style="color: #9bbb59;">
   <span style="text-decoration: underline;">I am testing for another string</span>
 </span>'

DECLARE @startIndex INT, @endIndex INT

SET @startIndex = CHARINDEX('<span style="text-decoration: underline;">',@MainString,CHARINDEX('<span style="text-decoration: underline;">',@MainString)) + 42
SET @endIndex = CHARINDEX('</span>',@MainString,CHARINDEX('<span style="text-decoration: underline;">',@MainString))

DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@MainString,@startIndex,@endIndex - @startIndex))

SET @MainString = (SELECT REPLACE(@MainString, '<span style="text-decoration: underline;">','<span style="text-decoration: underline;"><u>'))

SET @MainString = ( SELECT REPLACE(@MainString, '<u>' + @text + '</span>','<u>' + @text + '</u></span>'))

SELECT @MainString
```

Which outputs as expected:

```
i want to how tags are 
<span style="color: #9bbb59;">  
  <span style="text-decoration: underline;">
    <u>I am testing for another string</u>
  </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this

```
SELECT REPLACE('i want to how tags are <span style="color: #9bbb59;"><span 
   style="text-decoration: underline;">working</span></span>?', '<span 
   style="text-decoration: underline;">working</span>', '<span style="text- decoration: underline;"><u>working</u></span>');
```

I hope it will work

Comment: What about the dynamic text inside `<u><u>`?

Comment: I want dynamically. I gave only samples. i want to work in tables data.